# Why 'import' keyword is importing OS module commands along with the parent class that I want to import?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-import, importerror

I've saved my parent class "RE" in a parent.py file and while working in a child class inside another child.py file, i used "from parent import RE" and it successfully imported the main class, however it also imported the OS module and the following print commands below OS, however it did't import CSV nor anything else from the 'parent.py' file!
Why is this happening?

```
import csv
import os
print('HELLO, THIS IS THE PARENT CLASS MODULE.\n\n')
print('Old Directory Address:',os.getcwd())
os.chdir('C:/Users/dim63838/PycharmProjects/pythonProject')
print("Updated Directory Address",os.getcwd(), '\n')
class RE:
     pass
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Importing a module executes it and then everything in the namespace of this module (regardless if defined in the module or imported into it from another module or package) is available for import.

Comment: Thanks Michael for mentioning that 'importing module executes it', however is there any reason, why it only imported 'os' library and not 'csv' library?

Comment: It should actually be possible to import both from the module. You should better also show the code which imports your `RE` module and how you check that `csv` isn't imported.

Comment: What makes you think it didn't import `csv`?  Note that the names defined by `import` statements aren't "transitive". Putting `import foo` in `bar.py` doesn't make the name `foo` available in a module that imports `bar`, though it can access it as `bar.foo`.

Comment: That is, putting `import parent` in `child.py` doesn't make `csv` available in `child.py`. If the child needs the CSV module, it should use `import csv` itself. (The module is not imported twice; the second `import csv` just brings the name into scope.)

Comment: Thank You @MichaelButscher and chepner. I hope, my programming skills will evolve and match yours soon!